# Error while trying to send messages with sendto()

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple server in C, but my program ends with a "Bad adress" error. My goal is to keep receiving messages via UDP, and sending them to every address of an array.
This is the array (and counter):

```
struct sockaddr_in add[MAX_CLIENTS]; clients = 0;
```

This is how I add more clients:

```
add[clients] = echoClntAddr; clients++;
```

`echoClntAddr` is, of course, a `struct sockaddr_in`; this line is executed after I use the `recvfrom()` function to receive the message from it.

And this is where I try to make the broadcast:

```
for(int i=0; i < clients; i++){
            printf("\n Sending to client %ul",add[i].sin_addr.s_addr);
            if(sendto(sock, m, echoStringLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &add[i], sizeof(add[i])) != echoStringLen) 
                die("\n Error in sendto()");
        }
```

What's wrong? I am incorrectly storing the adresses or passing the wrong arguments to `sendto()`?

Comment: The MS page about [`sendto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto) says *"Return Value. If no error occurs, `sendto` returns the total number of bytes sent, **which can be less than the number indicated by `len`**. Otherwise, a value of `SOCKET_ERROR` is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling `WSAGetLastError`."* (my bolding). What happens it you test a return value of `SOCKET_ERROR`?

Comment: Note that "broadcast" in the context of UDP has a very specific meaning -- IPv4's UDP has a function where you specify a special broadcast-IP address as the packet's destination address, and the single packet will get sent to every host on the LAN.  This question appears to be about unicast packet sending instead (albeit sending unicast packets to multiple destinations).  You may want to update your question to specify that more clearly.

Comment: @WeatherVane he never mentioned he's on Windows

If you're not on Windows, try to use `perror` to get the Error from `errno`.
(The documentation linked by @WeatherVane doesn't mention `errno` so I won't assume it's used.

Could you provide a complete minimal example?

Comment: @Inrin fair enough, I looked up the MS usage, because I use MSVC. OP does not mention `errno`.

Comment: @WeatherVane "*If no error occurs, `sendto` returns the total number of bytes sent, **which can be less than the number indicated by `len`**.*" - that only applies to connection-oriented sockets, like for TCP. Message-oriented sockets, like for UDP, can't send partial messages, so if `sendto()` can't take the complete data in one go, it simply fails.

Comment: @wox a "Bad Address" error is `EFAULT`, which `sendto()` will report if either `m` is not a pointer to valid memory, or `echoStringLen` exceeds the allocated size of the memory that `m` points to. The rest of your `sendto()` parameters are fine as-is.

Comment: Just to add, if the message is too big, it sets `EMSGSIZE` (Posix/Linux) and `WSAEMSGSIZE` on Windows/Winsock